# How to get timestamp for any attributes in Orion

Tags: fiware-orion

I've my context in Orion within multiple attributes;

how can I also get the attributes' timestamp ("modDate") via GET query?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with [Builtin Attributes documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#builtin-attributes) (to which `dateModified` belongs):

> Builtin attributes are not rendered by default. In order to render a specific attribute, add its name to the `attrs` parameter in URLs (or payload field in POST /v2/op/query operation) or subscription (`attrs` sub-field within notification).

So, in the case of GET, you have to use something like this:

```
GET /v2/entities?attrs=*,dateModified
```

The `*` is needed to include all the regular attributes. If you ommit it and use just `?attrs=dateModified` you will get only `dateModified` and no other attribute.

**EDIT:** in the case you want to get not the *entity dateModified attribute* but the *attribute dateModified metadata* is similar. In this case, from [Builtin Metadata documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#builtin-metadata)

> Builtin metadata are not rendered by default. In order to render a specific metadata, add its name to the `metadata` URL parameter (or payload field in POST /v2/op/query operation) or subscription (`metadata` sub-field within notification).

So:

```
GET /v2/entities?metadata=*,dateModified
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the same result also used: GET /v2/entities?options=dateModified

Comment: I have multiple attributes, dateModified is generic (for all attributes); I'm interested to get the timestamp for any attributes. Is it possible

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide that piece of information

Comment: With regards to ?options=dateModified I strongly encourage not using it, as it is a deprecated alterantive (thus, can be removed in a next Orion version). See: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#deprecated-features

Comment: If you find my answer ok, please tick it as valid. It is not to feed my ego :) but for helping other people showing it is a correct solution to the issue.